UWP - Cannot load assembly '00010001002382fcb1069523...'. No metadata found for this assembly
I have a UWP app, to be built for MS Store and in side-loading.
Therefore, I need to build the app in Release using .NET Native compiler, with target x64 and ARM64.
I always got the app built, installed and ran correctly, until a few days ago.
My last build (actually I tried 5 times the same codebase...) has correctly completed the build, is installed perfectly fine, but when you run the actual app, I see the following exception at runtime:
Cannot load assembly '00010001002382fcb1069523, Version=4.2.1.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a'. No metadata found for this assembly. - inner exception: Cannot load assembly '00010001002382fcb1069523, Version=4.2.1.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a'. No metadata found for this assembly. - stack trace is 
at System.Reflection.Runtime.General.QSignatureTypeHandle.Resolve(TypeContext) + 0x43   
at System.Reflection.Runtime.ParameterInfos.RuntimeMethodParameterInfo.get_ParameterType() + 0x45
at SharedLibrary!<BaseAddress>+0x7ce8fa
at SharedLibrary!<BaseAddress>+0xc3c319
at SharedLibrary!<BaseAddress>+0x7142c0
at SharedLibrary!<BaseAddress>+0xb260d0
at SharedLibrary!<BaseAddress>+0xb2d3d7
at SharedLibrary!<BaseAddress>+0xc35da7
at Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.DefaultContractResolver.GetCallbackMethodsForType(Type, List`1&, List`1&, List`1&, List`1&, List`1&) + 0x126
at Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.DefaultContractResolver.ResolveCallbackMethods(JsonContract, Type) + 0x56
at Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.DefaultContractResolver.InitializeContract(JsonContract) + 0x19a
at Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.DefaultContractResolver.CreateLinqContract(Type) + 0x39
at Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.DefaultContractResolver.CreateContract(Type) + 0x298
at System.Collections.Concurrent.ConcurrentDictionary`2.GetOrAdd(TKey, Func`2) + 0x9a
at Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.DefaultContractResolver.ResolveContract(Type) + 0x1d
at Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalReader.Deserialize(JsonReader, Type, Boolean) + 0x7a
at Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializer.DeserializeInternal(JsonReader, Type) + 0xf3
at Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(String, Type, JsonSerializerSettings) + 0xd6
at Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject[T](String, JsonSerializerSettings) + 0x36
at LTSQLiteStore.MobileServiceSQLiteStoreExtensions.ConvertToJObject(MobileServiceJsonSerializerSettings, Object) + 0x43
at LTSQLiteStore.MobileServiceSQLiteStoreExtensions.DefineTable[T](MobileServiceSQLiteStore, MobileServiceJsonSerializerSettings) + 0xed
at LTSQLiteStore.MobileServiceSQLiteStoreExtensions.DefineTable[T](MobileServiceSQLiteStore) + 0x41
at LTClientModel.LocalDB.DBUtils.BuildStore[T]() + 0xe2

Here is my Default.rd.xml file:
<Directives xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/netfx/2013/01/metadata">
  <Application>
    <Assembly Name="*Application*" Dynamic="Required All" />
    <Assembly Name="System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager" Dynamic="Required All" />
    <Type Name="LiquidTextUWP.Utils.UWPUtils" DoNotOptimize="true" DoNotInline="true"/>
    <Type Name="LTBaseSync.Utils.ConfigReader" DoNotOptimize="true" DoNotInline="true"/>
    <Type Name="LiquidTextUWP.Controls.Menu.LTSelectionMenuView" DoNotOptimize="true" DoNotInline="true"/>
    <Type Name="LiquidTextUWP.Controls.Documents.FoxitUtils" DoNotOptimize="true" DoNotInline="true"/>
  </Application>
</Directives>

What can I do?
Thank you very much!

What sqlite library did you use? Can this unexpected behavior be reproduced on both x64 and ARM?

@JunjieZhu-MSFT we use SQLitePCLRaw.bundle_e_sqlite3 as NuGet for SQLite. We reproduce this deterministically in x64, I cannot try now on ARM64.

Since everything was working a few days ago, maybe you can try to clear the whole project and rebuild it. Or try to add SQLitePCLRaw.bundle_e_sqlite3 in Default.rd.xml file.

Thanks @JunjieZhu-MSFT. I already tried multiple times cleaning rebuilding etc. => nothing worked. But I am intrigued by the possibility to add SQLitePCLRaw.bundle_e_sqlite3 in Default.rd.xml file. In the link you sent I can specify a class or a single method, but SQLitePCLRaw.bundle_e_sqlite3 is a full assembly, so what should I add in the Default.rd.xml?

Have you modified the project configuration or update any NuGet packages before?

It's been 4 years that this project is going on, and I did around 200 builds/deployments during this period, most of them changing NuGet packaging, messing with configuration, etc.
